# При нажатии кнопки Next падает приложение

Tags: android

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

public class CapitalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button nextButton;
    private Button answerOne;
    private Button answerTwo;
    private Button answerThree;
    private Button answerFour;
    private int index = 0;
    private TextView questionTextView;

    String[] quest = {
            "France",
            "Sweden",
            "Poland"
    };

    String[][] answ = {
            {"Paris", "Rome", "Moscow", "York"},

            {"Warsaw", "Stockgolm", "beijing", "Kuala-Lumpur"},

            {"Warsaw", "Bagkok", "London", "Phuket"}
    };

    /* private Questions[] questions = new Questions[]{
             new Questions(R.string.questions_france, "Париж"),
             new Questions(R.string.questions_sweden, "Стокгольм"),
             new Questions(R.string.questions_poland, "Варшава")
     };
     */
    private void updateQuestion() {
        // int question = questions[index].getTextResId();
        if (index == quest.length) {
            index = 0;
        };
        questionTextView.setText(quest[index]);
        answerOne.setText(answ[index][0]);
        answerTwo.setText(answ[index][1]);
        answerThree.setText(answ[index][2]);
        answerFour.setText(answ[index][3]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.capitals);

        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // index = (index + 1) % questions.length;
                index++;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

проблема собственно в чем: при нажатии кнопки Next приложение падает. В logcat'е пишет Attempt to invoke virtual method........on a null object reference

Comment: Кнопки answerOne, answerTwo и т.д. где-нибудь инициализируются?

Answer (score 1):

Когда происходит нажатие на кнопку `next` вызывается метод `updateQuestion()`, он в свою очередь пытается присвоить кнопкам `answerOne` и т.д. текст, но эти кнопки не проинициализированны.

Их необходимо проинициализировать в `onCreate()` также, как вы инициализировали кнопку `next`

`TextView` тоже необходимо проинициализировать

Comment: Кнопки answerOne ...Four не инициализированы, да. При их нажатии ничего не происходит. но проблема была и без них. Приложение крашится именно при нажатии кнопки Next. 
как я и говорил, убрав кнопки one ...four ничего не изменяется.

Comment: С макета убрали? Этого мало, у вас в коде есть объявление четырех кнопок и в методе updateQuestion() вы к ним обращаетесь и пытаетесь им текст присвоить

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в чем проблема!!
не хватало 
questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

Comment: опередили меня немного)

Comment: Спасибо за желание помочь) 
нашел сам, причем случайно. до этого день копался не мог понять.